# Spring Webapp using MySql in OpenShift platform

Tags: java, mysql, spring, openshift, paas

I just recently migrated from EC2 to OpenShift because Openshift has these applications that can be installed pretty quick in just 1 click(they call it cartridges), but there's one problem I have right now with this MySql cartridge.

I'n my spring webapp deployed in my OpenShift, hardcoding the db URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD for mysql server is not working. Most of the forums advised to use the environment variables to point the to db url, user,password but still not working.
But my concern is at least it will work even if I hardcoded the db url,username and password.

Any useful and helpful solution will be very much appreciated.

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1720)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:77)
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the relevant portion of your spring config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a scaled application, then you also need to use the environment variable for the database port, as it will not be the standard 3306.  You can check this by sshing into your gear and running `env | grep MYSQL` and see what it prints out.